# How to find when my business is created in google for google my business api

Tags: node.js, analytics

I am trying to find google my business insight for my business since the beginging.
How to find when that business or location is registered or created using api .

tried getting the 
gmb insight api
`https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{aacountid}/locations/{location_id}/`

but there is no `registration date` or `created_at`

How to find when did the business started with google so that analytics since the begining can be found .

Thankyou